# MYSQL Multiple Joins duplicates the output

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT p.id, p.first
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN job j ON ( p.job_id = j.id )
LEFT JOIN favourites f ON ( p.company_id = f.company_id )
WHERE p.company_id = 1
```

I have 3 tables.

`Job` `Favourites` `People`

Each have `company_id` inside them. When I try the above it outputs `p.id`,`p.first` twice. If I remove one of the `JOIN`s then the output is as expected but without the table which was removed.

Comment: how about INNER JOIN?

Comment: @JohnRuddell it still duplicates the output

Comment: can you post some data?

Comment: please provide structure of 3 tables

Comment: What you have here is just an one-to-many relationship which gives you exactly what you are saying. Like you have a registry on `people` and you have two jobs to this people on table `job`. So you should show some data and your desired result. But, as simple as your query is just to add a DISTINCT you resolve your problem. `select DISTINCT p.id, p.first .....`

Comment: @JorgeCampos if the p.id and p.first are different per row for the company_id then DISTINCT wont make a difference --- aka if more than one person works at the company than DISTINCT wont matter

Comment: Since OP said that it is showing the `p.id,p.first` twice I assume that he does not want this particular combination to repeat. And for that DISTINCT will work

Comment: Yea but I don't know if he means that its a repeated row or that its showing two rows

Comment: @Donald would you add some more info to your question? Like some data sample from the three tables and what is the result you desire?

Comment: @JorgeCampos if it is distinct you should go ahead and put an answer down if its not then you can just edit later :) seems like a viable answer though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments what you have here is just an one-to-many relationship which gives you exactly what you are saying.

Like you have a registry on people and you have two favourites to this people on table favourite. To  clarify consider the following situation:

Table people:

```
id   name        job_id    first
 1     John         1        1
 2     Campos       2        2
```

Table job

```
id   job
1     Programmer
2     Developer
```

Table favourites

```
company_id   desc
 1            Blah
 2            Bleh
 1            Blih
```

On the above model a people have two favourites registries.

For your model it seems that one people can have only one job, but since you did not specify what the table `favourites` looks like it is probably the the situation i've shown is generating your problem. So to quickly solve it you can use a DISTINCT command like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.first
  FROM people p
       LEFT JOIN job j 
              ON ( p.job_id = j.id )
       LEFT JOIN favourites f 
              ON ( p.company_id = f.company_id )
 WHERE p.company_id = 1
```